# OBS doesn't detect Capture Card audio

Tags: streaming, obs

I just plugged in my USB capture card and I'm not getting any audio. Not just can't hear it, nothing even appears in it's Audio Mixer slider.
I tried putting it's Audio Output Mode to "Output desktop audi" and "Capture audio only", neither worked.
I went to the Advanced Audio Properties and went through all the options, no change.

VLC can detect the audio, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the capture card. I can hear it neither in my headset nor in the livestream, absolutely no audio.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a checkmark on "Use custom audio device" which opened a dropdown in which I picked "Digital Audio Interface (2- USB Digital Audio)"